# Python Numpy Track all 0's in an explosive spread

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

## Question:

I have a python numpy array list that is of RxC dimensions containing all 1's except one place with a 0.

Lets say we have 3x4 for now. And I have to track its adjacent from 0 point on to see the explosive spread of it.

Check input for visual representation of the context.

Its related to chain reaction spread, But I can't wrap my head around on how i can track it in a 2D array.

There can be `N' number of zero's and How do I mark all its surrounding Places as 0 as well.

## What I tried:

I tried doing some math over it but works only for one place with this formula

`0` - position 3,3

size - 3x4

3-3, 4-3 = 1 iteration. But its wrong.

## Input:

**Starting:**

```
[
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1],
[1,1,0,1],
[1,1,1,1]
]
```

**Iteration 1:**

```
[
[1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0]
]
```

**Iteration 2:**

```
[
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0]
]
```

## Output:

The chain reaction spread took 2 iterations to complete.

Comment: it can be done fairly simple way. `O(nxnxm)` .  `for each iteration if matrix[i][j]= 0  make the adjacent nodes to 0`. m is no of iterations. Are you looking for a optimised solution or something?

Comment: I am looking for a realtime solution where there can be any number of 0's and we can still calculate the spread and total iterations it took.

Comment: And you just want the Output (in the example 2), or the iterations as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_cdt

arr = np.ones((4, 4))
arr[2,2] = 0
distance_transform_cdt(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

You can max it to get `n`

```
distance_transform_cdt(arr).max()
# 2
```

Tested with 2 zeros:

```
arr2 = np.ones((5, 5))
arr2[2,3] = 0
arr2[1,1] = 0
arr2

array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])

distance_transform_cdt(arr2)

array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, **There can be multiple 0's that occur**, This solution won't work for that.

Comment: Its like a **fire spread in a forest kind of problem, What happens when there are multiple places the fire starts**.

Comment: @High-Octane I've tried with 2 zeros. Can you give it a check? Or perhaps add another example with multiple zeros?

Comment: Sure, Let me give it a shot. :)